# What is ".in" file in java that is for inputs?

Tags: file

in a Programming Contest, I found at the start of each problem such of these

> Program :    vote (cpp|java)
>
> Input:   vote.in
>
> Baloon Color:     Gold

what is the ".in" extension and the Baloon Color ?

Comment: not really a Java question..

Comment: just look at the source code of the vote program

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ".in" file extension doesn't have any special meaning as far as Java or C++ is concerned. It's just an extension to indicate (to humans) that it is an input file.

Answer (score 4):

`.in` is nothing more than something used by programming contests to designate input.  The contents are just a plain text file.